# Ruby on rails Login form not saving attributes and login workflow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jruby, jrubyonrails

I'm a newbie for **jRuby/Ruby on Rails** and trying to create a website (Learning purpose).

In this web application users need to register to the system. Upon successful login attempt they are allowed to maintain their own dashboard which is a simple phone contact details management.

I'm using

1. `jruby 9.0.5.0 (2.2.3)`
2. `Rails 4.2.6`
3. `Windows 10`
4. `MySQL` in `XAMPP` installation

**Question no 1**

In my signup, when I try to insert a new user, function works **but I'm not getting the values in my textfields**. Instead I'm getting null values in my table. What am I doing wrong?

This is my create `User`

```
   class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
       def change
          create_table :users do |t|
             t.string :name
             t.string :email
             t.string :password

             t.timestamps null: false
          end
       end
    end
```

This is my `user.rb` model

```
   class User < ActiveRecord::Base
       begin
           attr_accessor :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation
       end
       validates :name, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true, :length => { :in => 3..20 }
       validates :email, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true
       validates :password, :confirmation => true #password_confirmation attr
       validates_length_of :password, :in => 3..20, :on => :create
   end
```

This is my `users_controller.rb`

```
   class UsersController < ApplicationController
       def login

       end

       def create
           flash[:notice] = ''
           @user=User.new(user_params)
           if @user.valid?
               @user.save
               flash[:notice] = "You signed up successfully"
               render 'users/login'
           else
               flash[:error] = "Form is invalid"
               render 'users/signup'
           end

       end


       def signup
           @user = User.new
           flash[:notice]=''
           flash[:error]=''
       end

   private
       def user_params
             params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
       end

   end
```

This is my `signup.html.erb`

```
   <div class = "content">
       <h1>Sign Up</h1>
       <p>Maecenas nisi nunc, vulputate ac tempus eget, suscipit ut sapien. Aenean fringilla ultricies ultricies. 
Mauris aliquet nunc in velit posuere, in convallis purus ullamcorper. 
Nam imperdiet lacus lacus, quis finibus diam dapibus a. Nullam quis accumsan libero. </p>

       <div class = "form_data">
             <%= form_for(:user, :url => {:controller => 'users', :action => 'create'}) do |f| %>
                 <table>
                     <tbody> 
                        <tr>
                           <td> Name : </td>
                           <td> <%= f.text_field :name %> </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td> Email : </td>
                           <td> <%= f.text_field :email %> </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td> Password : </td>
                           <td> <%= f.password_field :password %> </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td> Re-type Password : </td>
                           <td> <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %> </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td> </td>
                           <td> <%= f.submit :signup %> </td>
                        </tr>

                    </tbody>
                 </table>
             <% end %>

        </div>
        <% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
            <%= content_tag :div, msg, :id => "flash_#{name}" %>
        <% end %>

   </div>
```

**Question no 2**

How to create a `contact_details` `table (id, name, phonenumber, owner_id)` with `user_ID` of the user table as the `foreign key (owner_id)`.

**Question no 3**

How to create the login algorithm nice and neat. Any links to a tutorial is appreciated

**Question no 4**

How to edit the Select queries in `Jruby/Ruby on rails` so that I can get the details based on the logged user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer 1**

When you use `attr_accessor` it tells the model that you don't want these attributes to be saved in the database, but just used as model properties in the application. Remove the block below and the data should save fine.

```
begin
  attr_accessor :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation
end
```

**Answer 2**

The best place to read on this is the [Rails Guides, Active Record Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html). Explanation hardly gets better than that.

Here's a gist of what you need to do without spoon feeding is:

You will need to generate a `UserDetail` model/scaffold with the parameters. `id, name, phonenumber, user_id`  (note the use of user_id. It is a rails convention for foreign key).

Your model declaration will then look like,

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user_detail     
end

class UserDetail < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

**Answer 3**

Here's the best ever video on how to create authentication from scratch by Ryan Bates.  http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch-revised

**Answer 4**

The video in Answer 3 will answer this question as well, but basically when you have that authentication setup, you can get the details simply by doing 
`current_user.user_detail`

**Update**

Just realized that the video link I posted is a pro video and requires subscription. If you already have one, and I strongly recommend it if you are learning rails, you should be able to see it. If not,  there are plenty of **[Authentication from scratch](http://www.emilyplatzer.io/2014/06/29/user-authentication.html)** tutorials out there, most based on that video. Following any will do.  Also FYI, That site is currently just charging for one month's subscription, and all following months are being renewed free for now (as of writing this.). So its a really good deal, for high quality learning material.